# Boolean function analysis on random graphs?

Tags: probability, reference-request, graph-theory, boolean-algebra, random-graphs

[Random graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomGraph.html) have some properties that are determined in some random way such as edge probabilities in the interval $[0,1]$.

Ryan O'Donnell's book *"Analysis of Boolean Functions"* (2014) has analysis on boolean functions, an example 11.73 on graphs. I want to understand boolean function analysis on graphs such as expected values on connectivity function and conditional expected values with symmetric differences on having a vertex and not a having a vertex.

**Where can you find books, references on boolean function analysis on graphs with things such as expected values?**

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? I'm afraid I can't understand it at all (even after looking at example 11.73, about the Max-Cut problem).

Comment: @Graffitics potentially related to this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754021/probability-spaces-over-graphs-which-area-has-focus-on-them): I am trying to learn probability spaces over graphs. I don't know yet which area research them.

Comment: From what I understand, I'd say you are interested in random graphs theory, and since you look at $p \in (0,1)$, you should probably have a look at Lovász's work (he has a book "Large networks and graph limits") or the shorter "Graphons, cut norm and distance, couplings and rearrangements" by Janson for a more probabilistic view of the field.

Comment: @Graffitics yes on random graphs theory, probably. But the publications have no word about things such as expected value and st-connected? Is this more related to Probabilistic Method (such as the book Probabilistic Method by Noga Alon: Random Graphs p.155) where they calculate threshold function for a graph theoretic property such as connectedness? I think this material looks promising but is there any full treatments about the properties and observed distributions in graphs?

Comment: They have no words about connectedness because when $p\in (0,1)$ the graph is connected with high probability, the threshold for connectedness is at $p \sim n \log n$. I'm not sure this result is in the Alon/Spencer, you should find it in the Erdős-Rényi papers on random graphs. I'm not sure how you can say "the publications have no word about expected value", since the theory of graphons is built about the expected value of the cut metric, which is a much better notion of connectedness for dense graphs. They show what graph parameters of the graph distributions can be estimated correctly.

Comment: @Graffitics I could find threshold at $t(n)= \frac{\log n}{n}$ such as [Erdos-Renyi 1961 (page4)](http://economics.mit.edu/files/4622) and [Erdos-Renyi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29), does this imply $p\sim n\log n$? What about expected value for sparse graphs?

Comment: Sorry about the mixup between $p$ and the number of edges in the graph. The threshold is indeed $p \sim \log n / n$, which means the graph has approximately $(p \cdot n^2=)n \log n$ edges. 
If you want to look at sparse graph, there's a lot of research on the weak local limit (Benjamini Shramm, Aldous, ...) and corresponding evaluation of parameters based on that. The reason the two are separated is because most of the tools and problems are only relevant in either the sparse or dense case.

Comment: @Graffitics I am trying to understand more precisely [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YhNeV.png). What do you think would be the most relevant to this? Something on Sparse random graphs and algebraic percolation theory?

Comment: From what I understand, you are interested in a specific problem (it seems to be st-reliability?), so the most relevant literature is the literature concerning this problem (just look at in on your favorite search engine). Then follow the references.