# Probability spaces over graphs: which area has focus on them?

Tags: reference-request, random-graphs, probabilistic-method, reference-works, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose a simple graph $G$. Now consider probability space $G(v;p)$ where $0\leq p\leq 1$ and $v$ vertices. I want to calculate globally-determined properties of $G(v;p)$ such as connectivity and expected value of indicator function $$\mathbb E_{p\sim [0,1]^n}(\phi(G))$$ in terms of st-connectedness where $p$ follows let say uniform distribution.

I want to understand which area investigates such structures. Extremal graph theory? Probabilistic Method? Random Graphs? Or some other?

**Which area has a focus on probability spaces over graphs?**

Comment: Do you mean that you have a fixed graph $G$ and a probability distribution on the vertices, and you want to study properties of these two? I'm not sure I understand how this should work, in that I don't see how the probability links to the graph theory. With random graphs, the edges which are present are based on some probability distribution, so there is a clear connection between the two.

Comment: Thank you for observation. $ST$-cut can be defined in terms of edges or in terms of vertices: a vertex-cut disconnects vertices $S$ and $T$ where the vertex-cut has a corresponding edge-cut, if $v$ in vertex-cut, then edge-cut contains all edges $\{u,v\}$ where $u$ is adjacent to $v$. Now if $p_{vertex-v}\sim\mathbb{Pr}_1$, then $p_{edge-u-v}\sim \mathbb {Pr}_1$. So here random graph with some probability distribution $\mathbb{Pr}_1$.

Comment: I'm confused on the model that you want. Is it one of these two? Fix some graph $G$. First model: For each edge $e$ in $G$, we include this edge in our random (sub)graph with probability $p$ independent of other potential edges. Second model: For each vertex $v$ in $G$, we include this vertex in our random induced (sub)graph with probability $p$ independent of other potential vertices.

Comment: @DPoole the second is the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the model defined in the following way: Fix some graph $G$. For any $p \in [0,1]$, each vertex $v$ in $G$ is in the random induced subgraph with probability $p$ independent of other vertices.

This model is an instance of [site percolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory). Two popular introductory textbooks to Percolation Theory are *Percolation* by Bela Bollobás and Oliver Riordan and *Percolation* by Geoffrey Grimmett.

Comment: My teacher said that site percolation is not an example of this *"Random graph $G(n,p)$ is a probability space over graphs of order $n$ determined by $P[{i,j}\in E(G)]=p$ where $i$ and $j$ are distinct elements of the vertex set $V(G)$. The events $\{i,j\}\in G$ are independent."* -- can you understand the meaning? Is the formulation Erdös-Renui or some other random graph model?

Comment: That model is different than the one described in the comments to the original post. In those comments, you said that the *vertices* were randomly chosen, not the edges. If you take $K_n$, and for each edge you keep it with probability $p$ and delete it with probability $1-p$, then you have the random Erdős–Rényi graph $G(n,p)$. Now if you take $K_n$ (or any other graph), and for each *vertex*, you keep it with probability $p$ and delete it with probability $1-p$, then you have what is commonly called site percolation.

Comment: So bond percolation is an example of Erdös-Renyi graph $G(n,p)$ where edges removed with probability $p$? Can I mark the probability space over graph $G$ with $G(n,p)$ for site percolation? Or is $G(n,p)$ notation preserved for only the Erdos-Renyi where edges removed with probability $p$ (bond percolation?)?

Comment: I would avoid using $G(n,p)$ unless you mean the Erdős–Rényi random graph. Although you can think of $G(n,p)$ as looking into bond percolation on $K_n$, the types of questions in bond percolation and random graphs are typically different. In bond percolation, the underlying base graph is typically a lattice or some other infinite graph with symmetry rather than $K_n$. Also, the notation for site percolation is usually this: the base graph is $\Lambda$ and the random (sub)graph is denoted $\Lambda_p^s$ or just $\Lambda_p$. The $s$ denotes "site".

Answer (score 0):

I start the thread with an observation:

> 1. The Probabilistic Method book by Noga Alon has a treament of random graphs on page 155 where they calculate the expected value and the threshold function for graph-theoretic property such as connectedness