# Which Random Graph model on Reliability network when vertices deleted?

Tags: random-graphs, operations-research, network, reliability

The reliability network when edges deleted corresponds to binomial random graph model that is also called Bernoulli Model. The [page 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=RjnqVoB4VmUC&pg=PA3) of Random Graphs book (2000) by Svante Janson, Tomasz Luczak and Andrzej Rucinski states that the reliability network where vertices deleted instead do not correspond to the Bernoulli Model.

**What is the Random Graph model for Reliability Network where vertices deleted intstead of edges?**

Comment: Is this your model: Fix some (large) graph $G$. For each vertex $v$ in $G$, we keep it with probability $p$ (and so delete it with probability $1-p$) independently of all other vertices. At the end, we take the *induced* subgraph on those vertices that we kept.

Comment: @DPoole yes, accurately the [vertex-induced subgraph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html) where the removal of vertex $u$ removes all incident edges to the vertex $u$. And yes the vertices are deleted independently from all other vertices.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754021/probability-spaces-over-graphs-which-area-has-focus-on-them). This random graph is typically referred to as *site percolation*. Although the most known results of the field deal with infinite graphs, the proofs typically analyze large subgraphs (which you then look at a random subgraph of this subgraph).

Comment: @hhh I see that you created ([tag:reliability]) tag. It is customary that the tag-creator also creates the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reliability/info) explaining the intended usage of the tag.